# Modify data frame with respect to another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
> test
     par1  par2  par3 progress
1    TRUE  TRUE FALSE        0
2    TRUE FALSE  TRUE        0
3    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE        0
4    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE        0
5    TRUE FALSE FALSE        0
6   FALSE FALSE  TRUE        0
7    TRUE FALSE  TRUE        0
8    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE        0
9    TRUE FALSE  TRUE        0
10   TRUE FALSE  TRUE        0
...

> rules
    par1  par2  par3 progress
1   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      0.1
2   TRUE  TRUE FALSE      0.3
3   TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
4   TRUE FALSE FALSE      0.7
...
```

I'd like to modify `test$progress <- test$progress + rules$progress` according to values of `par1`, `par2` and `par3` i.e. in case of `test[1, ]` its progress should be increased by `0.3`, in case of `test[2, ]` its progress should be decreased by `0.2` and so on. After appropriate changes of `test$progress` its `par1`, `par2` and `par3` values will be recalculated and the process will be repeated many times.

Data frame `test` has around 4k rows and data frame `rules` has all combinations of `TRUE/FALSE` for its parameters.

I know how to do this in a loop, but I know it is not the best way to do it. What is a better way?

Comment: Your question is about how to code in R, not about statistics. This Q should be asked on [SO]. If you wait a bit, we will migrate it there.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Please migrate it. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing to apologize for. It's just a note for future reference. It shouldn't take too long to migrate it.

Comment: @chriss are you relating the data frames using row names?

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar no, I don't have row names

Comment: Why does `TRUE  TRUE FALSE` result in `0.1`? According to `rules` this combination should result in `0.3`

Comment: @DatamineR You are absolutely right. I corrected the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can `merge` the two tables on the first three columns:

```
df <- merge(test, rules, all.x = TRUE, by = c("par1", "par2", "par3"))
df[,5][is.na(df[,5])] <- 0
df$progress = df$progress.x + df$progress.y
df <- df[c(1:3,6)]

df
    par1  par2  par3 progress
1  FALSE FALSE  TRUE      0.0
2   TRUE FALSE FALSE      0.7
3   TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
4   TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
5   TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
6   TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
7   TRUE  TRUE FALSE      0.3
8   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      0.1
9   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      0.1
10  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      0.1
```

Pay attention at the new ordering.

Or with `dplyr`

```
left_join(test, rules, by = c("par1", "par2", "par3")) %>%
replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% mutate(progress = progress.x + progress.y) %>% select(-c(4:5))
    par1  par2  par3 progress
1   TRUE  TRUE FALSE      0.3
2   TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
3   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      0.1
4   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      0.1
5   TRUE FALSE FALSE      0.7
6  FALSE FALSE  TRUE      0.0
7   TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
8   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      0.1
9   TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
10  TRUE FALSE  TRUE     -0.2
```

Comment: What if progress in test data.frame is not 0?

Comment: humm.. you could do this in a single line using `transform` like this `transform(merge(test, rules, by= c("par1","par2","par3")), progress = progress.x + progress.y)`

Comment: It still wouldn't solve the problem with summing `NA` and `0` which results in `NA`

Comment: Yeah but there will be no 'NA's unless test values are not in rules but that's fine, its your taste! btw you missed pipe in your dplyr solution